# What is "bit shift parameter" in OpenCV(for drawing shape codes)?

Tags: python, opencv

I've tried to put a point in the picture with decimal coordinates(x,y).

I got that coordinates from Facemesh of Mediapipe.

For example, I want to put a dot on the middle of eyes, so I got the coordinates of index 243 and 464.

I got the NDC coordinates so I denormalized it.

[index 243.. x:419.5781707763672, y:266.46667671203613, z:10.594706565141678]

[index 464.. x:454.8342933654785, y:270.0289077758789, z:5.107446044683456]

So I want to put a dot at [x: 437.206..., y: 268.247...] in the picture using OpenCV.

but if I write the code like this:

```py
import cv2
cv2.line(img, (437.206, 268.247), (437.206, 268.247), (0,0,0), 1)
```

```
TypeError: integer argument expected, got float [ WARN:0] terminating async callback
```

Q1. How can I use x and y values with float(decimal) type??

Q2. What the 'shift' parameter means?

```py
cv2.line(img, (x,y),(x,y),color,thickness,linetype,***shift***)
```

Can I use it for float value?

Comment: You can't have `float` type. Change it to `int`

Comment: pass shift=4 or so, and use `int(x * 2**shift)` (and so on)

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Thank you for the answer. What "shift = 4" means? I cannot understand about "shift" or something because I can't find any example of that parameter..

Comment: this is fixed point numbers. the `shift` is the number of fractional bits (bits on the right side of the decimal point).